# Removing duplicate month and years in a array of dictionary and then save it into another array according to the year and month - Swift iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary *var year_month = [String: Any]* and i'm appending daily sale data with year month. here is the array after appending data

```
[["year": "2019", "month": "July"], ["year": "2019", "month": "July"], "month": "July"], ["month": "July", "year": "2019"], ["month": "July", "year": "2019"], ["month": "July", "year": "2019"], ["year": "2019", "month": "July"], ["year": "2019", "month": "August"], ["month": "August", "year": "2019"], ["year": "2019", "month": "August"],["year": "2020", "month": "July"], ["year": "2020", "month": "July"], "month": "July"], ["month": "July", "year": "2020"], ["month": "July", "year": "2020"], ["month": "July", "year": "2020"], ["year": "2020", "month": "July"], ["year": "2020", "month": "August"], ["month": "August", "year": "2020"], ["year": "2020", "month": "August"]]
```

then I need to store in an another array like this  *var final_year_month = Dictionary<String, Any>* like this

```
final_year_month.append(["year" : "2019", "value" : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    ["year" : "2020", "value" : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]])
```

how I can remove duplicate years and months and can append all the months as per years
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe not all 12 months will exists for a year in your first dictionary? Also, have you considered using a struct instead for your sales data so you don't need these dictionaries? Finally, please add your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your response. Actually i'm using a model of sale which stores daily sale with day month years etc. I just separate the months in a dictionary for better understanding because in dailly sale i have sale agains card cash total etc so thats why i did this. 
i just want to maintain an dictionary to search the other sale attributes by using year and month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a dataset as such:

```
let dataSet = [["year": "2020", "month": "January"], ["year": "2020", "month": "February"], ["year": "2019", "month": "March"], ["year": "2019", "month": "April"]]
```

Group the data set by year:

```
let yearAndMonthGroupedByYear = Dictionary(grouping: dataSet) { yearAndMonth -> String? in
    return yearAndMonth["year"]
}
```

This gives us:

```
[Optional("2020"): [["year": "2020", "month": "January"], ["year": "2020", "month": "February"]], Optional("2019"): [["year": "2019", "month": "March"], ["month": "April", "year": "2019"]]]
```

For each group, we want to

1. Extract the year and the months that correspond to that year
2. Get rid of duplicate months
3. Return a dictionary consisting of a year and an array of unique months

Like so:

```
let result = yearAndMonthGroupedByYear.compactMap { year, yearAndMonthArray -> [String: Any]? in
    guard let year = year else { return nil }
    let months = yearAndMonthArray.compactMap { $0["month"] }
    let uniqueMonths = Set(months)
    let arrayOfUniqueMonths = Array(uniqueMonths)
    return ["year": year, "value": arrayOfUniqueMonths]
}
```

This gives us:

```
[["year": "2020", "value": ["January", "February"]], ["value": ["March", "April"], "year": "2019"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so so much :)